# Visual Basic SqlException

Tags: c#, sql, sqlclient

new to coding and currently making a database system for my a-level project. I am attempting to take the input from text boxes and input them into my database, however I am presented with an 'SqlException was unhandled error, Additional information: Incorrect syntax near 'Date of Birth'. Here is the code written.

```
Connection.Open();
        SqlCommand Command = new SqlCommand(null, Connection);
        Command.CommandText = String.Format("Insert into EmployeeTable (Forename,Surname,'Date of Birth','Email address','Phone number',Country,Address,City,Postcode,'Skill 1','Skill 2','Skill 3','Job 1','Job 2','Job 3','Employee Availability') Values('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}','{5}','{6}','{7}','{8}','{9}','{10}',{11},{12},{13},{14})", ForenameInputBox.Text, 
            SurnameInputBox.Text, DoBInputBox.Text, EmailInputBox.Text, CountryInputBox.Text, AddressInputBox.Text, CityInputBox.Text,
            PostcodeInputBox.Text, Skill1InputBox.Text, Skill2InputBox.Text, Skill3InputBox.Text, Job1InputBox.Text, Job2InputBox.Text,
            Job3InputBox.Text, EmployeeAvailablityBox.Text);
        Command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Connection.Close();




CREATE TABLE [dbo].[EmployeeTable] (
[EmployeeID]            INT           NOT NULL,
[Forename]              NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
[Surname]               NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
[Date of Birth]         DATETIME      NOT NULL,
[Email address]         NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
[Phone number]          NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
[Country]               NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
[Address]               NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
[City]                  NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
[Postcode]              NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
[Skill 1 ]              NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
[Skill 2]               NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
[Skill 3]               NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
[Job 1 ]                BIT           NOT NULL,
[Job 2 ]                BIT           NOT NULL,
[Job3 ]                 BIT           NOT NULL,
[Employee Availability] BIT           NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([EmployeeID] ASC)
```

^My table definition

---

EDIT:

```
 Connection.Open();
        SqlCommand Command = new SqlCommand(null, Connection);
        Command.CommandText = "Insert into [EmployeeTable] (Forename,Surname,DateofBirth,Email address,Country,Address,City,Postcode,Skill1,Skill2,Skill3,Job1,Job 2,Job3,EmployeeAvailability) Values(@forename, @surname, @dateofbirth, @emailaddress, @phonenumber, @country, @address, @city, @postcode, @skill1, @skill2, @skill3, @job1, @job2, @job3, @employeeavailability)";
        Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@forename", ForenameInputBox.Text);
        Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@surname", SurnameInputBox.Text);
        Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dateofbirth", DoBInputBox.Text);
        Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@emailaddress", EmailInputBox.Text);
        Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@country", CountryInputBox.Text);
        Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", AddressInputBox.Text);
        Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@city", CityInputBox.Text);
        Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@postcode", PostcodeInputBox.Text);
        Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@skill1", Skill1InputBox.Text);
        Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@skill2", Skill2InputBox.Text);
        Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@skill3", Skill3InputBox.Text);
        Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@job1", Job1InputBox.Text);
        Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@job2", Job2InputBox.Text);
        Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@job3", Job3InputBox.Text);
        Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@employeeavailability", EmployeeAvailablityBox.Text);
        Command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Connection.Close();
    }
}
```

^An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: Incorrect syntax near 'address'.

Comment: Your column won't be named `'Date of Birth'`, what's its actual name? Same for the rest inside inverted commas. Also, look at parameterized queries, your current code is open to attack.

Comment: Here is my table definition, I thought that it would be Date of Birth as that's what it says here?

Comment: Column names won't have spaces.

Comment: I see, so shall I remove these and then try again?

Comment: @Equalsk although it is not advisable to have spaces, it is entirely possible

Comment: My bad, TIL. Still look at parameterized queries though ;-)

Comment: The spaces in your columns are inconsistent. Please double-check the spelling

Answer (score 1):

You should qualify your column names with brackets, like this: `[]` instead of single quotes / apostrophes

here's is a revision on your query:

```
/// .. reformatted sql string
Command.CommandText = String.Format("Insert into [EmployeeTable] (Forename,Surname,[Date of Birth],[Email address],[Phone number],Country,Address,City,Postcode,[Skill 1],[Skill 2],[Skill 3],[Job 1 ],[Job 2 ],[Job3 ],[Employee Availability]) Values('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}','{5}','{6}','{7}','{8}','{9}','{10}',{11},{12},{13},{14},{15})", ForenameInputBox.Text, 
        SurnameInputBox.Text, DoBInputBox.Text, EmailInputBox.Text, CountryInputBox.Text, AddressInputBox.Text, CityInputBox.Text,
        PostcodeInputBox.Text, Skill1InputBox.Text, Skill2InputBox.Text, Skill3InputBox.Text, Job1InputBox.Text, Job2InputBox.Text,
        Job3InputBox.Text, EmployeeAvailablityBox.Text);
```

Comment: This has fixed this error, but it now states that I have

'Additional information: Invalid column name 'Job 3'.

There are more columns in the INSERT statement than values specified in the VALUES clause. The number of values in the VALUES clause must match the number of columns specified in the INSERT statement.'

Comment: However there are 15 values being passed and 15 columns since I've set the EmployeeID to auto-generate, do I still need to add something for this?

Comment: You specify 16 columns in the query.

Answer (score 0):

It's not really the best practice to capture your database columns names with spaces in them. I would change the column names to use camel casing (ie: DateOfBirth), that way you would not need to use the single quotes in the string which is the cause of the error here.

If it's a must that you persist with the spaces in the column names then change 'Date of Birth' to [Date of Birth] and so on for the other columns that contain spaces.

Comment: Okay thank you for the help, will bear that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple contributing factors that could lead to errors.

1. 16 columns but 15 input parameters
2. Column with value not provided, such as 'Phone number'
3. Column name not match in query text. 'Job 3' in query, 'Job3' in table
4. Use square brackets [] instead on single quote as column qualifier
5. Is there validation of the input text? Such as illegal characters, proper data type format, exceeded length etc.

Comment: Hi, just corrected these things, thank you. And no I haven't added any validation as of yet. Going to look up how.

Answer (score 0):

It's best practice to not have spaces in your column names, instead use underscores or camel casing to achieve a readable name:

Underscores:

> date_of_birth

Camel casing:

> DateOfBirth

You should look at parameterized queries when running commands against your database. If you do not you're open to attack, for example someone could potentially delete your entire table.

[Relevant XKCD on 'Little Bobby Tables'](https://xkcd.com/327/)

You code should look more like this (I have removed some columns for brevity):

```
Connection.Open();
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(null, Connection);
command.CommandText = "Insert into EmployeeTable (Forename,Surname,[Date of Birth], ... , ...) Values(@forename, @surname, @dateofbirth,...,...)";
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@forename", ForenameInputBox.Text);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@surname", SurnameInputBox.Text);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dateofbirth", DoBInputBox.Text);
...
...
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
Connection.Close();
```

Comment: I used this format and received this error message:

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: No mapping exists from object type System.Windows.Controls.TextBox to a known managed provider native type.

Comment: I'm guessing somewhere you've missed the .Text off the end of the name of a Text box, e.g. you've put SurnameInputBox instead of SurnameInputBox.Text

Comment: Yeah that was right, now it comes up with another error. I find it hard to translate the error messages into what they actually mean, I've added the code to my answer and the latest error beneath it.

Comment: I think it's where you l have put "Email address" as a column name. It's should be in square brackets if it has a space.

Comment: Really appreciate the help, it now says: "An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: Incorrect syntax near '2'." Which 2 is it referring to?

Comment: Sorry can't chat yet as I do not have enough rep.

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'EmployeeID', table 'C:\USERS\USER\DOCUMENTS\VISUAL STUDIO 2015\PROJECTS\WPFAPPLICATION\WPFAPPLICATION1\EMPLOYEEDB.MDF.dbo.EmployeeTable'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

The statement has been terminated.

Comment: It doesn't allow nulls but I wish for it to auto generate the Employee ID? Do i need to insert into this field?

Comment: I didn't ask you to chat, it's an automatic suggestion from the site. You have not told the EmployeeID column to auto populate. You should ask a separate question including the schema shown in this question about how to make it auto populate.